# How to fetch the data of a specific model from the collection list that is present to the user in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, models

I have a list view that displays some contents from the api and along side a button that when clicked should show the details of the corresponding item from the list-view on another page, how to associate the button to the specific id and how to present a generic url that accepts these ids to route accordingly. I saw many similar posts but I didn't know how to route those or can't understand how each model is called at that route. Here's my current app, where I've not generalised the routing instead each button is associated to the first id and a route like `/1` which takes it to a view to display details of the first element from the collection alone.

**pollsscript.js**

```
//defining the model
var QuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // urlRoot : "http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/question/",

});

//defining collection
var QuestionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url : "http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/question/",
    model: QuestionModel

});

//list view of all the questions
var QuestionListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.page',

    render : function(){

        var context = {};
        this.questionCollection = new QuestionCollection();
        this.questionCollection.fetch({
            success: () => {

                  context['models'] = this.questionCollection.toJSON();

                  var template = _.template($('#question-list-template').html(),{});

                  this.$el.html(template(context));
             }
        })
        return this;
    }
});

//individual questions
var QuestionDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.page',

    render : function(){

        var context = {};
        this.questionCollection = new QuestionCollection();
        this.questionCollection.fetch({
            success: () => {

                  context['model'] = this.questionCollection.get(1).toJSON();

                  var template = _.template($('#question-detail-template').html(),{});

                  this.$el.html(template(context));
             }
        })
        return this;
    }
});


var questionListView = new QuestionListView();
var questionDetailsView = new QuestionDetailsView();

var PageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        '1' : 'details',
    },

    home : function(){
        questionListView.render();
    },

    details: function(){
        questionDetailsView.render();
    },

});

//initializing router and setting up history for routing to work
var pageRouter = new PageRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>All polls</h1>
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- main page template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="question-list-template">
        <table class = "table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <!-- <th>Date Published</th> -->
                    <th>Votes</th>
                    <th>Popular responses</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <% _.each(models, function(model){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= model.question_text %></td>
                        <!-- <td><%= model.pub_date%></td> -->
                        <td><%= model.total_votes%></td>
                        <td><%= model.pop_response%></td>
                        <td><a href="#/1" class="btn btn-info">Show details</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="question-detail-template">
        <div>
            <div><%= model.question_text %><div/>
            <div>
                <% _.each(model.choices, function(choices){ %>
                    <div><%= choices.choice_text %></div>
                    <div><%= choices.votes %></div>
            <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pollsscript.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>All polls</h1>
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- main page template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="question-list-template">
        <table class = "table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th> ID </th> -->
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th>Votes</th>
                    <th>Popular responses</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <% _.each(models, function(model){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <td id="id"><%= model.id %></td> -->
                        <td><%= model.question_text %></td>
                        <td><%= model.total_votes%></td>
                        <td><%= model.pop_response%></td>
                        <td><a href="#<%= model.id %>" class="btn btn-info show-details">Show details</button></td>
                        <!-- <td><a href="#<%= model.id %>" class="btn btn-info show-details" data-id="<%= model.id %>">Show details</button></td> -->
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="question-detail-template">
        <div>
            <div><%= model.question_text %><div/>
            <div>
                <% _.each(model.choices, function(choices){ %>
                    <div><%= choices.choice_text %></div>
                    <div><%= choices.votes %></div>
            <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pollsscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**pollsscript.js**

```
//defining the model
var QuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // urlRoot : "http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/question/",

});

//defining collection
var QuestionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : "http://localhost:8000/polls/api/v1/question/",
    model: QuestionModel
});

//list view of all the questions
var QuestionListView = Backbone.View.extend({   
    el: '.page',
    template : _.template($('#question-list-template').html()),
    render : function(){    
        var context = {};
        this.questionCollection = new QuestionCollection();
        this.questionCollection.fetch({
            success: () => {
                  context['models'] = this.questionCollection.toJSON();
                  this.$el.html(this.template(context));
             }
        })
        return this;
    },
    // events: {
    //  'click .show-details' : 'viewDetails',
    // },
    // viewDetails : function(e){
    //  var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
    //  var item = this.questionCollection.get(id);
    //  var questionDetailsView = new QuestionDetailsView({
    //      model: item
    //  });
    //  questionDetailsView.render(); //get and pass model here 
    // }
});

//individual questions
var QuestionDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    template : _.template($('#question-detail-template').html()),
    render : function(){
        var context = {};
        context['model'] = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(context));
        return this;
    }
});

var PageRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        ':id' : 'details'
    },
    home : function(){
        var questionListView = new QuestionListView();
        questionListView.render();
    },
    details : function(id){
        //alert(id);
        var context = {};
        this.questionCollection = new QuestionCollection();
        this.questionCollection.fetch({
            success: () => {
            var item = this.questionCollection.get(id);
            var questionDetailsView = new QuestionDetailsView({
            model: item
            });
            questionDetailsView.render();
            }
        })

    }
});

//initializing router and setting up history for routing to work
var pageRouter = new PageRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

I tried this, later, I associated the data-id with the button and gave the model.id I fetched from the api and then got the id on click and then passed the model to be rendered on the detail-view.

Still this doesn't change the router in anyway so still looking for a better way to do it.

**Edit**
Updated the code and fixed by associating model id with href, and created routes to fetch and get the model from in the router function.